# jQuery how to remove a div in variable

Tags: jquery

```
var divs = $('div.first, div.two, diw.three');
```

if i want remove '.first' in divs variable, like:

```
divs.get('.first').remove();
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: you need remove a element in array or a tag div with class .first in a html code?

Comment: In html code, thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [**`filter()`**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function for this.

```
divs.filter('.first').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

try, but check array structure.

```
var divs = ['div.first', 'div.two', 'diw.three'];

// Find and remove item from an array
var i = divs.indexOf("div.first");
if(i != -1) {
    divs.splice(i, 1);
}
alert(divs);
console.log(divs);
```

eg:https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/x53Lae5o/

For delete a div element in html code.

```
$("div").filter('.first').remove();
```

Comment: Question doesn't mention anything to do with arrays and the jQuery doesn't reference the cached collection